# How do I unlock "Because you Begged" in Halo: MCC?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

I've jumped off this cliff in Pillar of Autumn so many times to assassinate this Elite. I know the challenge is pretty finicky just like the old achievement, but is there a way to help increase my odds of unlocking it?

Comment: Hopefully this stops someone from throwing themselves off a literal cliff trying to get this challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying myself for about 3 hours I resorted to Youtube/Forums. I finally found a solid tutorial video. I think the most important part is deleting your save as I was able to unlock the challenge near instantly after that.

Pre step:

[image]

After that:

1. Start the Pillar of Autumn mission (Difficulty does not matter)
2. Melee / Jump your way to the cliff to avoid a checkpoint
3. Wait until the Elite is in a good location and stop melee'ing to get the checkpoint
4. Save & Quit the game. (This avoids the Halo: Reach checkpoint system pulling you back a checkpoint from repeated deaths.
5. Resume the game and yeet yourself off the cliff. Aiming at the left shoulder of the Elite seems to work better, and if you perform a lunge you will not be able to get the achievement.

Source:

Answer (score 0):

I have probably done more than 100 damn falling assassinations at this point. I don't know that deleting your save does anything, although I did try that twice. What I can say for sure is that the assassination you perform MUST be the neck stomp animation, any other will not work. To accomplish this you basically have to be looking almost straight down and be almost on top of or very close to right on top of the elite. Hope this helps.